# How would i use 'Console.ReadLine' multiple times?

Tags: c#

i'm trying to write a program that asks the user to think of a number between 1-100, and it will then ask "Is the number higher or lower than 50?" If the user inputs "Higher" the program will execute a random number between 50-100. I have got everything working correctly except the fact "userInput" will only work for one line, example: If i was to input "Higher" it will work no problem, the program then asks if the new number generated is correct and asks the user to input either "Yes/No" and at that stage the program won't execute the input...But, if you enter "Yes/No" before "Higher/Lower" it wil work, so my guess is, because i've declared "userInput" to 'Console.ReadLine' it won't read what the users real input is on the second line they write, my question is...what else could i do instead of declaring it to that string? As you can tell i'm new to programming! Any feedback is much appricated!

Code: http://pastebin.com/cEw3tccq

Comment: Since I'm at work now, pastebin can't be accessed because of firewall. Paste your code as a text in your question..

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing the user input. For example in this snippet from your code

```
Random aboveFifty = new Random();
int aboveF = rnd.Next(50, 100);
Console.WriteLine("is your number {0} ", aboveF + "? \n[Yes/No]\n");
Console.ReadLine();
```

the string from `Console.ReadLine()` is not assigned to a variable. You will need to assign the user input to the variable you declared for it earlier e.g.

```
Random aboveFifty = new Random();
int aboveF = rnd.Next(50, 100);
Console.WriteLine("is your number {0} ", aboveF + "? \n[Yes/No]\n");
userInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I did declare it as Console.ReadLine though?

Comment: You did, but you only assigned to it once. You need to assign the string that's returned each time you call `Console.ReadLine()` to a variable so that you can act on it. You only store the result of your first call to `Console.ReadLine()`, thereafter whenever you call `Console.ReadLine()` you do not assign the resulting string to any variable; in effect you just throw the resulting string away.

Comment: Perhaps you need to read up on the difference between declaration and assignment. Your line `string userInput = Console.ReadLine();` declares a string variable named `userInput` and assigns the result of a call to `Console.ReadLine()` to the new variable. Think of that as two things: declaration and assignment. Thereafter if you want your `userInput` variable to store the value of subsequent calls to `Console.ReadLine()` you will need to assign it those new values.